# 'fArray' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, scope

Hello I'm having this issue with my C++ problem I'm working on.

Here is the code

**Cell.h**

```
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

class Cell
{

private:

    int level;
    int row;
    int column;

    //declares a variable called ptrFunction_array which is an array of 3 function pointers.
    typedef void (*ptrFunction[])(void);

    static void function1()
    {
        cout << "I'm function 1";
    }

    static void function2()
    {
        cout << "I'm function 2";
    }

    static void function3()
    {
        cout << "I'm function 3";
    }

public:
    Cell(int currentLevel, int currentRow, int currentColumn)
    {
        level = currentLevel;
        row = currentRow;
        column = currentColumn;

        ptrFunction = new *fArray[3];
        fArray[0] = function1();
        fArray[1] = function2();
        fArray[2] = function3();
    }
    virtual ~Cell();
    void tick()
    {
        int randomNumber = rand() % 3;

        cout << "Cell(" << level << ", " << row << ", " << column << ") ";

        fArray[randomNumber];
    }
};



#endif // CELL_H
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Cell.h"

using namespace std;


Cell ****myArray;

int main()
{
    int level = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    char userInput = 'y';

    srand (time(NULL));

    do
    {
        cout << "Please input the amount of levels: ";
        cin >> level;
        cout << "Please input the amount of rows: ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Please input the amount of columns: ";
        cin >> column;
        cout << endl;

        myArray = new Cell *** [level];

        // Set random number to the elements of the array
        for (int currentLevel = 0; currentLevel < level; currentLevel++)
        {
            myArray [currentLevel] = new Cell ** [row];

            for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < row; currentRow++)
            {
                myArray [currentLevel][currentRow] = new Cell * [column];

                for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < column; currentColumn++)
                {
                    myArray [currentLevel][currentRow][currentColumn] = new Cell (currentLevel, currentRow, currentColumn);
                    myArray [currentLevel][currentRow][currentColumn] -> tick();
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to try again? (y / n) ";
        cin >> userInput;

        cout << endl;

        if ((userInput == 'y') || (userInput == 'Y'))
        {
            for (int currentLevel = 0; currentLevel < level; currentLevel++)
            {
                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < row; currentRow++)
                {
                    for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < column; currentColumn++)
                    {
                        delete[] myArray[currentLevel][currentRow][currentColumn];
                    }
                    delete[] myArray[currentLevel][currentRow];
                }
                delete[] myArray[currentLevel];
            }
            delete[] myArray;
            myArray = NULL;
        }

    }while (userInput != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```

I notice that my fArray isn't inside the scope. the Line `ptrFunction = new *fArray[3];` is where my error is. I've recently started learning C++ so I'm in the process of trying to understand why my `typedef void (*ptrFunction[])(void);` isn't correctly initializing the `fArray`for my program. The goal of my program is to be able to create a 3 dimensional array and be able to point to the Cell Objects and be able to track the location x,y,z.

Why does an error like this happen?

Comment: `Cell ****myArray;`  You've got to be joking.

Comment: Think really hard on what you are doing here: `Cell ****myArray`

Comment: What is `fArray`? I don't see anything in this code called `fArray`.

Comment: I don't see any declaration of fArray either. Is it a class written somewhere?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm? How would you make a "3-dimensional array" of pointers? (Quote marks because it's actually a chain of 1-dimensional ones)

Comment: Another odd bit is `ptrFunction = new *fArray[3];` Here `fArray` seems to be a type. But here `fArray[0] = function1();` it's being used as a variable.

Comment: I wrote it in the .h but i completely goofed up and didnt create in main.cpp

Comment: Thinking on that a bit more, I think you have it backward. Do you perhaps mean, `ptrFunction *fArray = new ptrFunction [3];` to build an array of `ptrFunction` named `fArray`? Also note that `fArray` would be a local variable, visible only in the bounds of the `Cell` constructor.

Comment: Hotels are good when they are 4 stars.  C++ programming is a different story when it comes to 4 stars.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie LOL Im just starting to learn this according to my class it's the base course of action to take.

Comment: @immibis I would start by using `std::vector` in some sort of capacity, whether it's a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>>` or a `std::vector<Cell>` and simulate a 3D array.

Comment: @JeanP It is not how any C++ programmer, whether new or experienced, should approach a problem like this.  Creating a pointer with 4 levels of indirection is, well, insane.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I apologize, This a little more difficult for me to learn. I was under the wrong impression that this was the right method.

Comment: In C++ (and slightly less in C) pointers are generally avoided. Every pointer has to point at something. That something may be moved, deleted or otherwise go away. Every block of memory you allocate with `new`, you must also release with `delete` and you have to select the right time to delete it because someone else could still be using it.

Comment: @user4581301 So in my case, what would be a better course of action rather than using pointers?

Comment: Still trying to work through that in your case. Your intent isn't all that clear from your code. @PaulMcKenzie may have the right of it with his suggestion of `vector` of `vector`s because it eliminates the bulk of the memory management, but this depends on how you intend to use `Cell`. You might not need to go more than 2 `vector`s deep. 4 dimensional modelling is quite uncommon.

Comment: @JeanP Here is an example using `std::vector`.  All I did was compile it.  The runtime error is due to me not supplying user input in the `do` loop, but you should get the idea.  http://ideone.com/Qwzwnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the four star pointer for now and stick to what's giving OP the most immediate grief.

A quick walk-through:

```
Cell(int currentLevel, int currentRow, int currentColumn)
{
    level = currentLevel;
    row = currentRow;
    column = currentColumn;
```

Not bad to here. But...

```
    ptrFunction = new *fArray[3];
```

This says assign to the variable `ptrFunction`, which must already exist and doesn't, a newly allocated array of 3 `fArray`s. The problem here is `ptrFunction` has been defined as a type, not a variable. `fArray` is not a type.

```
    fArray[0] = function1();
    fArray[1] = function2();
    fArray[2] = function3();
```

Use `fArray` as a variable, making what's gone wrong here somewhat clear.

```
}
```

Cell needs to look a bit more like this, but not exactly. More on that later.

```
Cell(int currentLevel, int currentRow, int currentColumn)
{
    level = currentLevel;
    row = currentRow;
    column = currentColumn;

    ptrFunction * fArray = new ptrFunction[3];
```

Now `fArray` is a variable that points to one or more objects of type `ptrFunction` (but the definition of `ptrFunction` is somewhat broken), and points `fArray` at three `ptrFunction`s. Technically it points at the first of three `ptrFunction`s.

```
    fArray[0] = function1();
    fArray[1] = function2();
    fArray[2] = function3();
}
```

Now we have an `fArray`, but it is a [local variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) and it only exists between the curly braces of `Cell`'s constructor. When the constructor exists, the pointer goes away. The memory allocated does not and is lost. Without `fArray` pointing to it, you can't easily find it to use or delete it. `fArray` needs wider [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) so that A) the memory isn't lost, and B) so that `tick` and other members of `Cell` can see it.

```
class Cell
{

private:

    ptrFunction * fArray;
    int level;
```

and in the constructor:

```
Cell(int currentLevel, int currentRow, int currentColumn)
{
    level = currentLevel;
    row = currentRow;
    column = currentColumn;

    fArray = new ptrFunction[3];
```

That fixes the can't find `fArray`.

My recommendation is to get one `Cell` working and then take a stab at getting a 1 dimensional array of `Cell`s working. When you have one dimension, then try two. You might find that's all you need.

## Edit

Forgot to mention this: Function pointers to members functions are an absolute expletive deleted to get right. [Here is a page on common pitfalls and how to avoid them.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

And here is how we avoid this smurf in the here and now of Modern C++: [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). The tutorials at the bottom of the linked document pages probably describe how to use them for simple cases better than I can.

Comment: Okay so moving forward I'm starting to understand a bit more. I edited my code. Now I'm running into a new error `error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` researching this it seem it had to deal with my array pointer being one star rather than three from what I understood from a similar post online. the Error occurs on `fArray = new ptrFunction[3];`

Comment: I'm sticking to my recommendation that you cut back and make sure you have a single `Cell` working properly. Right now you have a lot of code and no one piece works correctly to get a good foundation on which you can build. This greatly increases the amount of debugging you have to do because you have more places you need to look. Write a little bit of code. Make sure it works. Write more code. Make sure it works. Writing everything all at once is a sucker bet. For now just get a working `Cell` that allocates and frees all of its resources and you can call and exercise without it crashing.

Comment: It also gives you a nice, clean base from which to ask well-targeted questions on little bits of complete code.